# What's letting the horizontal scroll still happen on Android?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I've looked through a bunch of different questions here and tutorials elsewhere, trying various solutions to stop the horizontal scroll on my website on Chrome for Nexus 5.

The website is http://kennethfrancis.com

This hasn't seemed to change anything:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1" />
```

I want the HR to snap to full screen width when tablet or phone-sized, but to disable the horizontal scroll. Other tips about the HTML and CSS are appreciated.

EDIT: Looks like the GMail logo is wiggling when I hover it in Chrome 30.. Any ideas about that would be appreciated also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the margin style on your hr.. min-width of 700px is one cause
and the width in media query is 200%.. make it 100%

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px)
    hr {
    margin-left: -20%;
    width: 200%;
    margin-top: -60px;
    }

    hr {
    margin-top: -80px;
    border: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block; 
    min-width: 700px; 
    background-color:#70B2FF;
    height: 1px;
}
```

change to

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px)
    hr {
    margin-left: -20%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -60px;
    }

    hr {
    margin-top: -80px;
    border: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block; 
    background-color:#70B2FF;
    height: 1px;
}
```